# UWP. Trying to async download pictures and get System.Exception: Calling Async synchronously, 'marshalled for a different thread'

Tags: multithreading, uwp

if interface need a picture it saves request in

```
ConcurrentDictionary<key, Delegate>
```

and when picture is on the disk read it and `SavedDelegate?.Invoke(key, byte[])`. 
But there is an error in this place:

```
private async void OnDelegateInvokeAsync(ImageItem item, byte[] body)
{
...
item.Image = new BitmapImage();
...
}
```

> System.Exception: Calling Async synchronously, 'marshalled for a
>   different thread' message (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E
>   (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))'

What is the best way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Where's the *rest* of the code? Where's the asynchronous call? How is `OnDelegateInvokeAsync` called? `async void` should **only** be used for event handlers. Methods that don't return results should use `async Task `. `async void` can't be awaited

Comment: Did you use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in the `await` call? That means execution *won't* return to the UI thread. Post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the image in the UI thread:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke( ()=> { item.Image = new BitmapImage(); ... } );
```

Comment: There's no reason to do this with `async/await`. If the OP get an exception it's probably because of that `async void` or another error that *doesn't* return execution to the UI thread